# receive role by an emoticon on the server's nickname

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I want to make a system of when the user changes their nickname on the server and puts an emoticon that I set in the configuration she wins a position for example:
Your nickname on the server is User and you change it to User  then you get a role because you used the  that was defined in the settings of the bot.

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the npm package [`emoji-regex`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-regex) to match unicode emotes in the member's nickname, the [`GuildMember.nickname`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=nickname) property to actually get the member's nickname, and the [`guildMemberUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate) event which will emit whenever someone's nickname is changed, among other things.

```js
const emojiRegex = require('emoji-regex'); // require the package

client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
 if (oldMember.nickname === newMember.nickname) return; // only execute code if the nick changed
 if (emojiRegex().test(newMember.nickname)) { // if the member has a unicode emoji in their nick
  // code...
 }
});
```

Comment: but this way I do not get a position for the member, for me to get the position is necessary the event guildMemberAdd

 guildMember.roles.cache.get('710952126058332250');
    ^

ReferenceError: guildMember is not defined

Comment: Did you define `guildMember`? What do you mean by position?

Comment: is it possible to put to work with username also as nickname?

Comment: Sure! You could use `GuildMember.displayName`. If a member has a nick, it will return the nick. Otherwise, it will return the username. You could also just use `GuildMember.username` if you *only* want the username.

Comment: I used it like this, newMember.username and it didn't work changing the username and newMember.displayName worked by changing the nickname